# Where would I find a high quality version of a wooden floor like this?

Tags: website-design, background, texture, stock-images, image-quality

It is to be used for background on a website. I like it exactly the way it is except that the image quality is not good enough. Looking for quality that will look good on a Retina screen. Must be able to license to use it (free or paid) for a commercial website.

I did of course already search Flickr, Google and some stock image sites. Primarily searched for "wooden floor", "wooden texture" and "wooden background".

Anyone knows where to find a high resolution one like it? Like one commenter mentioned, the image shown has been copied three times which is OK for the new image too - that way I can minimize the filesize the users browser has to download through the CSS background repeat-x method.

UPDATE: Found what I needed - please see my own answer below.

[image: light colored wooden floor]

Comment: Is there are reason why you can't just search stock photo sites, Flickr with Creative Commons as a filter, etc? It's a good idea to show evidence of prior research else people might just refer you to Google... :) p.s. (you may already be aware) the image you're showing is actually a small tall image flipped vertically then copied irregularly three times.

Comment: Good point! Thanks :) And yes, I did of course already search Flickr, Google and some stock image sites. Primarily searched for "wooden floor".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before asking this question I searched sites like iStockPhoto etc, but didn't find what I needed. But going through thousands of images at ShutterStock.com, I did find some that are usable. If you are looking for a similar image, try searching ShutterStock for "parquet seamless".

Thanks for wanting to help - appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help your need
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/28-high-resolution-wood-textures-for-designers/

Comment: Unfortunately not high enough resolution (looking for something that will look great on a Retina screen). But thanks :)

Comment: I disagree. Some of the ones there are 1024 x 1024 or larger and show a single plank. It would be easy to use one of those as a building block for a pattern like your sample, but much higher resolution.

Comment: @e100 The ones I found were too grainy IMHO, but I found usable ones on ShutterStock re. my answer below. Thanks for pitching in :-)

Answer (score 2):

A great site for things like this is http://cgtextures.com. Intended for use in 3D rendering, I tend to use them a lot for backgrounds and making grunge. Did I mention that it's free?

Answer (score 1):

If you need it very high resolution, why not buy a few pieces of wood (or flooring laminate) and scan them?

Comment: Because it would be much easer to just download, I guess :-)